# Определить стиль и тип речи

Tags: стилистика

Принято сравнивать архитектуру с музыкой. Как и музыка, архитектура таит в себе огромный по разнообразию диапазон эмоций. В камне может звучать ясная, мажорная мелодия классического ансамбля. Совсем иное и не менее сильное эмоциональное воздействие способна оказывать музыка средневекового города, где основная тема не мелодична, а скорее сбивчива и противоречива. Однако услышать вдохновенную музыку в камне может не каждый.

Помогите определить тип речи и стиль.

Comment: Предложение 1 и 2 связаны при помощи лексических повторов?

Comment: А 3 и 4-е предложения?

Answer (score 1):

Стиль-публицистический, но возможен и научно-популярный подстиль,нужен более полный текст. Сравнение архитектуры с музыкой возможно и в научно-популярных статьях научных журналов. Но скорее всего - публицистика, так как на 1 месте - воздействие на сознание и чувства читателя.

Тип речи - рассуждение.

Связь 1 и 2 предложений-лексический повтор и сравнит. союз.

Comment: При таком построении предложений это точно лексический повтор?

Comment: А что здесь особенного в построении? Если бы  у обоих предложений была инверсия, сказали бы, что связаны с помощью инверсии, но здесь этого нет. Что Вас смущает? Повтор-то есть.Или Вы имеете в виду-форму слова? Это одно и то же, при анализе текста чаще говорят о лексическом повторе.

Comment: Или Вы имеете в виду именно "повторов"-во множ. ч.. Это да, здесь два повтора-музыка и архитектура.

Comment: Я предполагала, что вдруг есть какой-то еще тип связи, мне неизвестный. Второе предложение начинается с сравнения. Это смутило.

В моем понимании, повтор -Я ехала мимо дерева. На дереве сидела кошка.

Answer (score 0):

Вводные к критической (заказной, скорее всего) журналистской рецензии к проекту реконструкции или воссоздания исторической застройки улицы, квартала. Слова складываются в банальные и лёгкие для прочтения фразы, при ближайшем рассмотрении - противоречивые: их назначение не в смысле, а настроении.

Comment: Это жанры, а не стиль.

Answer (score 0):

Стиль двух первых предложений - искусно завуалированная небрежность, способная привлечь внимание к тексту. При обычном порядке слов ("Архитектуру принято связывать с музыкой") было бы всё ясно: когда говорят об архитектуре, её часто сравнивают с музыкой - она чем-то её напоминает. А при имеющемся порядке создаётся впечатление, что есть общепринятое занятие: что-то сравнивать - особенно, архитектуру с музыкой. Во втором предложении высказана спорная идея о том, что эмоции принадлежат не людям, а плодам их творчества. Далее автор демонстрирует, что на самом деле он всё понимает: эти произведения способны вызывать эмоции у созерцателя, т.е. эмоции вовсе не "таятся в камне". Но читателя он успел привлечь, поэтому стиль всего абзаца можно назвать "оригинальным".

Comment: Это индивидуальный стиль писателя, а речь идёт о стилях РЕЧИ - разговорном, научном, деловом, публицистическом или художественном.

Comment: О какой такой ''завуалированной небрежности'' идет речь? Такого стиля ведь не существует? Здесь и так все ясно. А инверсия в первом предложении придает экспрессивность.